# Printing telegram image url - python Telethon

Tags: python-3.x, telegram, telethon

I'm trying to download images from the channels I'm following on telegram. I have managed to do that using telethon. However, for each downloaded image I'm trying to print its url. Is there a way of doing that?

Comment: You can only download photos using `Telethon` and the `download_profile_photo` method.

Comment: You can do it through the client.download_media method. What i'm trying to do is get a jpeg object of the image I receive.

Answer (score 1):

Best way to get a url to telegram image is get message id and username of a particular channel and put them together adding 'https://t.me/' at the beginning.